# Jquery checkbox ticking logic

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario where I am populating a datatable with n number of rows. The rows are populated in groups with a particular group id. Say, if there are 20 rows and they are divided into 4 groups, the first 5 rows will have a group id = 1, and the next 5 rows will have group id = 2 and so on. Each row will have its group id stored in a variable while creating the table.

My task is to give checkboxes to all the rows in a group but make only the first row of a particular group clickable. If the user checks/unchecks the first checkbox of a particular group, all checkboxes of that particular group are checked/unchecked.

I am achieving this by concatenating a counter with the id element of each row and then running a loop through the entire table on each row comparing the current row with its previous row on group id. If the group id of the current row is the same as previous row, it will get the state of checkbox of previous row and make the current checkbox the same state. Nothing is done if the group id of current row is different from previous row.

The problem here is, this logic is working absolutely fine but only once. The checking/unchecking all boxes works only after that it just checks/unchecks that particular box but not for the whole group.

Will provide more info if required.
Thanks

```
function checkBoxTick(){
for(var i = 0; i<$('#grouprowcount').val(); i++){
    if(i != 0){
    var previd = $('#groupId'+(i-1)).val();
    var nextid = $('#groupId'+(i)).val();
    if(previd == nextid ){
        $("#numid"+(i)).attr("checked", true);
        if($("#numid"+(i-1)).is(":checked")){
            
        $("#numid"+(i)).attr("checked", true);
        }
        else if($("#numid"+(i-1)).is(":not(:checked)")){
            $("#numid"+(i)).attr("checked", false);
            }
    }
    
    }   
}
```

Comment: Just a silly question. Since all checkboxes of same group share their state, why not just create only one checkbox per group?

Comment: Thats a perfectly valid question :)  The reason is that i am using Datatables plugin for my table and the number of columns needs to be same to number of rows. So each row in a group must have a checkbox in that column. Secondly, i am saving data in group but row wise. The data is saved for rows whose checkbox is ticked. So i think its better to give checkbox to each row for data saving.

Comment: I see. If you add the markup of like two groups and how you trigger the function, I am certain someone will have a look at it. From the feeling of it you shorten everything to one correct selector.

Comment: What do you mean add markup? I can add a gif of the issue if its allowed here. The function is called on the onclick of checkbox. So it will run everytime when any checkbox is interacted with.

Comment: add html code as well.

Comment: I think he meant HTML markup.  Markup is often used as short for HTML.

Comment: Disable all checkboxes but first, then propagate value when first change

Answer (score 1):

Please, check if this is what you need, otherwise I suggest you to show us a snippet of your own code.

```js
var groupCount = 2;

for(var i = 1; i <= groupCount; i++)
  $(':checkbox').filter('[name="group-'+i+'"]').not(':first').prop('disabled', true);

$(':checkbox').not(':disabled').change(function() {
  var group = $(this).attr('name');
  var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
  $(':checkbox').filter('[name="'+ group +'"]').prop('checked', checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="group-1" /></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="group-1" /></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="group-1" /></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="group-2" /></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="group-2" /></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="group-2" /></td></tr>
</table>
```